# Is there a specific Stack Exchange site for asking information regarding radio, their protocols, implementation in code, etc.?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Sample question:

> How can I send custom EWS (Emergency Warning Signals) over DAB+ using a SDR like HackRF One?

Comment: What does "implementation in code" mean?

Comment: Yeah some further details might be beneficial for a more pointed answer. Do you have a particular question in mind?

Comment: Added a question as per your request!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that question would be closed down. I really doubt that a private individual broadcasting an EWS signal would be legal.

Comment: @Snow Well yes but actually no, the HackRF One as a device, is fairly limitted in its sending capability. No one will be interrupted as the tests are taking place in an confined and isolated area. This is more like a proof of concept in development rather than "private individual broadcasting"

Comment: Related questions about homes for protocol questions: *[Good question etiquette for generalising questions regarding a protocol, not a framework or language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403528)* and *[Are questions about \[at-command\]s on-topic on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403258)*

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q the issue with this question is the fact that SO has a clear boundary and is a perfect example of a stack which encapsulates a single topic, namely: programming. The issue arrises when hardware is involved and specialized hardware at that. Radio tech questions isn't exactly the home for SO imo but I can be wrong

Answer (score 2):

https://ham.stackexchange.com/ (Amateur Radio)

Seems a good bet.

There are a few technically-focused sites on the network, knowing what your specific question is might narrow down the scope somewhat.

Comment: Note that HAM is for "private recreation, non-commercial exchange of messages". If this is about software development in an enterprise environment, don't bother. See their [help / on-topic](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and their [policy on broadcasting](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186/should-questions-on-broadcast-radio-be-specifically-off-topic) in particular.