# Looking for the right Stack Exchange site for parsing CAN bus data

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking for the right place to post about a [CAN bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) issue I'm looking for. Specifically parsing the data I'm getting in the messages I'm receiving.

Basically, I'm getting data from a CAN bus and want to be able to understand what the different messages mean, as some of them are clearly data but some packets are just the number 1 which I'm not expecting.

It doesn't seem right for Stack Overflow, which is where I mainly post, but I'm not sure where else would work for it?

Comment: Check their [on-topic page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first, but I think Electronics.SE is your best bet. Yes, they do have a [CAN tag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/can).

Comment: You have access to the J1939 standards documents? Also in my experience, not every manufacturer follows them exactly.

Comment: Related (also about protocols; on Meta Stack Overflow): *[Are questions about \[at-command\]s on-topic on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403258)*? and *[Good question etiquette for generalising questions regarding a protocol, not a framework or language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403528)*

Comment: (I would be able to recognise [CANopen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen) messages.)

Comment: @Mast but those are questions about the physical wiring of a CAN bus and devices that use it, not about the software processing data frames from it.

Comment: Somewhat related: *[Is there a specific Stack Exchange site for asking information regarding radio, their protocols, implementation in code, etc.?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357757/is-there-a-specific-stack-exchange-site-for-asking-information-regarding-radio)*